# Unix sort utility: use hexadecimal byte value as delimiter

Tags: unix, sorting

I'm wondering if I can use a hexadecimal value as delimiter of the Unix `sort` utility.
Basically I want to do something like:

```
sort -t '\x00' <input
```

But it doesn't work if I do it in the way above.

Comment: Are you looking to sort hexadecimal numbers? Or are you just trying to use x00 as a delimiter? If it is the latter, what is the use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the GNU `sort` manual, you will find:

> `-t separator`, `--field-separator=separator`
>
> Use character separator as the field separator when finding the sort keys in each
>   line. By default, fields are separated by the empty string between a non-blank
>   character and a blank character. By default a blank is a space or a tab, but
>   the LC_CTYPE locale can change this.
>   That is, given the input line `foo bar`, sort breaks it into fields `foo` and
>   `bar`. The field separator is not considered to be part of either the field preceding
>   or the field following, so with `sort -t " "` the same input line has three
>   fields: an empty field, ‘foo’, and ‘bar’. However, fields that extend to the end
>   of the line, as `-k 2`, or fields consisting of a range, as `-k 2,3`, retain the field
>   separators present between the endpoints of the range.
>   To specify ASCII nul as the field separator, use the two-character string `\0`,
>   e.g., `sort -t ’\0’`.

This worked with old (GNU CoreUtils 5.97) `sort`.

---

<s>There does not seem to be a way to do it on Linux.</s>  I've tried a number of tricks to get a NUL (0x00) byte into the delimiter, and the `sort` command complains:

```
sort: empty tab
```

You can't do it with <kbd>Control-V</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> as you are typing the command line; the shell (`bash`) does not like that.

I have a program `genchar` that writes bytes to output, so I tried:

```
sort -t "$(genchar 0)" ...
```

And that did not work either; I got the error from `sort`.

```
$ genchar 0 | od -c
0000000  \0  \n
0000002
$
```

If you were able to use control-A instead, then there'd be no problem.

Note that `sort` does not expand hex escape sequences in the '`-t`' option argument; you have to supply the actual byte you want to use.  You probably can't use newline as a field delimiter, either; if you did, what would the record delimiter be?

GNU 'sort' (from CoreUtils 5.97, at any rate; the current version is 8.12 - as of 2011-04-26) does support a `-z` option:

- `-z`, `--zero-terminated` end lines with 0 byte, not newline

This is not, sadly, what you are looking for.