# How to use NULL (\0) as the delimiter in GNU sort

Tags: bash, sorting

i am looking for a way to sort the results of `find` returning a number of directories correctly for further processing in a bash script. since filenames can't contain the NULL (\0) character i thought this would make a great delimiter for the results being piped to `sort`.

so this is what i would expect to work as described:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'xyz?' -print0 | sort -t $'\0'
```

but sadly i got the compaint `sort: empty tab`

looking around for a explanation a came across a [question leading to a similar result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797369/unix-sort-utility-use-hexadecimal-value-as-delimiter) that the op described as working fine (see lucas comment of apr 26th). in my case (using GNU sort v 7.4) this is seems different.

i also checked the output of find by piping into `od -c` but this only shows that the resulting folders are separated by NULL as expected.

has anybody here come across a similar scenario and possibly found a solution or explanation why \0 seem to be an impossible delimiter for sort?

looking forward to you answers...

**edit:** note that the find-command is used as an example here, a simpler way to test/illustrate this could be `echo "g\0u\0b\0k" | sort -t $'\0'`

Comment: does your version of sort not support the -z option?  I am on version 5.93 and that supports -z for null terminated entries.

Comment: oh well, yes it does! i really should understand the difference between line and field separator! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`-t` is the *field* separator. If you want to use `\0` as the *line* separator then you need to use `-z`.

Answer (score 3):

For further processing in a Bash script see, for example:

[Capturing output of find . -print0 into a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array)

```
# cf. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020
unset a i
while IFS='' read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
   a[i++]="$dir"        # or however you want to process each directory
done < <(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'xyz?' -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z)

printf '%s\n' "${#a[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"

# btw, you may use printf to add zero bytes
printf '%c\000' g u b k | sort -z | tr '\0' ' '
printf '%s\000' g1 u2 b3 k4 | sort -z | tr '\0' ' '
```

Comment: if checked out @jeff 's link to bashFAQ (very interesting!) and found the explanation for `IFS=''` in the while loop being necessary to not accidentially trim whitespace. so `IFS=` `IFS=''` and `IFS=$'\0'` would represent the same thing here: NUL

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-z` option to `sort` zero-terminated data sets:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'xyz?' -print0 | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: converting NULL into a newline at the end is an interesting idea but would in my opinion rise the same issues with filenames including a newline as if newline was chosen as a delimiter right from the start...